# facebook: fql Select from stream order by likes count desc

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get top 10 liked posts on a page. my query is :

```
select message,likes from stream where
source_id=<pageid> and is_published=1
limit 10
```

This is the returned data structure :

```
  "message": "message",
  "likes": {
    "href": "https://www.facebook.com/browse/likes/?id=<id>",
    "count": <likecount>, <- THIS IS THE FIELD I WANNA ORDER BY
    "sample": [
    ],
    "friends": [
    ],
    "user_likes": false,
    "can_like": true
```

How can I use order by clause to order by the likes : count field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add `ORDER BY likes.count` after the `WHERE` part and before the `LIMIT` part of your query.

With the `stream` table, you may need to up your `LIMIT` to get the results you want, and then truncate the returned results in your script. The stream table has some serious limitations on it by design:

- If you are allowing posts by others on your page, some users will have their privacy settings configured so their posts aren't returned by the API. Facebook filters these *after* it finishes evaluating the FQL, so it's rare that you will actually get 10 posts back when you request 10.
- Facebook limits the amount of history it searches in the `stream` table. I've found if you want to look at posts that are more than 1 month old, you need a `LIMIT` of at least 100. I've had a very hard time consistently retrieving posts more than 3 months old with the `stream` table.

Comment: the dot! that's what I was looking for! thanks for additional info on stream table.